# Retrieve Task List assigned to a particular user in camunda

Tags: drupal-8, camunda, tasklist

I am using **`camunda_bpm_api`** ( [git url](https://www.drupal.org/project/camunda_bpm_api/git-instructions) and the module in drupal8 [camunda+drupal8 sample module](https://github.com/zeropaper/cam_invoice_demo))  module connect my custom application in drupal to camunda server .

I was retrieving the **`process definitions`** using the function as follows :

```
private function fetchProcessDefinitions() {
    return \Drupal::service('camunda_bpm_api.process_definition')->getList();
  }
```

This is working properly .

How do i **retrieve the task assigned to a particular user** ? I was trying as follows :

```
public function fetchTaskList() {
    $payload = array('assignee' => 'nimyav');
    return \Drupal::service('camunda_bpm_api.task')->getList($payload);
}
```

But its **`retriveing all the tasks`** irrespective of the **`assignee`** ?

How do i achieve this ? any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to double check that you are getting the result, what happens if you call `curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/engine/default/task?assignee=nimyav" -H "accept: application/json"` assuming that your BPM engin is installed locally? If you don't use curl, you could just open the browser with the URL http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/engine/default/task?assignee=nimyav. Do you see tasks assigned to you only?

Generally, your request seems ok, but passing no second parameter to the `getList()` you are using it in HTTP GET mode. If you look at [Camunda REST docs](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.7/reference/rest/task/post-query/), you will notice that some methods are available as GET and as POST methods. Especially, I believe that Valentin designed the `getList` method to work in HTTP POST mode, because it is passing parameters in the request body (please check the `camunda_bpm_api/src/BPMPlatform/BaseService.php` for more details).

Please try to call the service like this:

```
public function fetchTaskList() {
    $payload = array('assignee' => 'nimyav');
    $usePost = TRUE;
    return \Drupal::service('camunda_bpm_api.task')->getList($payload, $usePost);
}
```

Comment: I got it right . thanks :) . Another question **how to i get the form-variables of a task process through rest API** ? When i tried **http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/engine/default/task/0ce473ad-a922-11e7-bc26-005056a64ad8/form-variables** Its getting a json that's not included the form-variables given in the form submission .

Comment: Hi can it also use like return **public function getTaskVariables($id, array $variables, $businessKey = NULL) {
        return $this->request('get', array(), '/process-instance/' . $id . '/variables');        
    }**
 as am getting the response via **http://192.168.1.188:8080/engine-rest/process-instance/e78f1bd3-a921-11e7-bc26-005056a64ad8/variables**